# What does property FeatureTypeName do in Styled Layer Descriptor (SLD) specification?

Tags: sld

I am studying the [Styled Layer Descriptor (SLD)](http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/sld) specification. I got a general grasp of how I can use it to style a map. I still have one question about the FeatureTypeStyle though.

When looking at the FeatureTypeStyle I see the property FeatureTypeName. What does this do? Say for example I got a layer called 'Rooms' and every room has a door (line) and figure (polygon) could I use the FeatureTypeName to say I only want to draw the doors?

Comment: this is a very broad question, could you try to edit it to narrow it to just one question.

Comment: In line with the comment by @iant I have edited the title of your question to refer to just the first question that you asked.  I recommend that you edit your question to focus on just that and then research/ask the other questions separately.